# Overriding ViewModelStore

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

Is it possible to provide once own implementation of a `ViewModelStore` for `ViewModelProviders` to use instead of the default one?

More precisely, I'm interested in adding `fun clear(vm: ViewModel)` (or using an index or something similar) functionality to the `ViewModelStore` so that I can clear a single view model of my choice, not just use the built in `ViewModelStore#clear`:

```
public final void clear() {
    for (ViewModel vm : mMap.values()) {
        vm.onCleared();
    }
    mMap.clear();
}
```

which clears all view models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I think you should **not** consider doing that, because that's an implementation detail of Architecture Components library. Most possibly you should come up with a better solution as a result of adapting your use-case to match guidelines/contracts exposed by `ViewModel`s API.

Nevertheless, let's examine possibilities of doing that.

Here's the code, that we should use in order to obtain a `ViewModel` implementation:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

What will this code result in, is that it will create an instance of [`HolderFragment`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/lifecycle/extensions/src/main/java/android/arch/lifecycle/HolderFragment.java), which is a retained fragment, and will attach it to `this`'s fragment manager (might be either `FragmentActivity`'s fragment manager or `Fragment`'s [child fragment manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager())).

This `HolderFragment` will be added with a [`HolderFragment.HOLDER_TAG`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/lifecycle/extensions/src/main/java/android/arch/lifecycle/HolderFragment.java#46), thus we are able to get an instance of this fragment from the fragment manager.

```
val holderFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android.arch.lifecycle.state.StateProviderHolderFragment") as HolderFragment
```

It's the `HolderFragment`, that creates an instance of `ViewModelStore` and [keeps that instance as a private field](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/lifecycle/extensions/src/main/java/android/arch/lifecycle/HolderFragment.java#49). There exists a getter for that field, but there does not exist a setter, which means, that the only way to "substitute" this object is by using reflection.

But before doing that, let's try to write a custom implementation of `ViewModelStore` class:

```
class MyViewModelStore : ViewModelStore() {

  private val mMap = HashMap<String, ViewModel>()

  internal fun put(key: String, viewModel: ViewModel) {
    val oldViewModel = mMap.put(key, viewModel)
    oldViewModel?.onCleared() // COMPILATION ERROR -> Cannot access 'onCleared': it is protected/*protected and package*/ in 'ViewModel'
  }

  internal operator fun get(key: String): ViewModel? {
    return mMap[key]
  }

  override fun clear() {
    for (vm in mMap.values) {
      vm.onCleared() // COMPILATION ERROR -> Cannot access 'onCleared': it is protected/*protected and package*/ in 'ViewModel'
    }
    mMap.clear()
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, we cannot do that, because `ViewModel#onCleared()` [has a `protected` package access](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/lifecycle/extensions/src/main/java/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.java#104), which makes impossible for us call it outside of the `android.arch.lifecycle` package. Again, we can use reflection to do that (but how good is that?).

Despite being not advised (by me), seems like that's also not achievable to do (without using reflection).

Comment: Thank you for your time! I was afraid of that, and I couldn't see a way around it other than with reflection neither, but thought I'd give this question a try. I should probably ask a separate question but, my thing is that I usually create single-activity apps, and therefore lots of view models can be bound to the same (only) activity. If I need to create a new (or another) instance of given view model I can't, because I will always get back the already existing one. And I haven't found a way to remove view models from an activity. Maybe you know of a way? If so, I can ask a anew question.

Comment: By design, only **one** instance of particular type of `ViewModel` is attached to an activity/fragment. In other word, `MyActivity` can ask for multiple types of `ViewModels` (e.g. `DogsViewModel`, `CatsViewModel`...), but each of these `ViewModel`s should be created only **once** during the whole lifetime of activity/fragment. Nothing restricts you to create new `ViewModel` types to fulfil your use-case. From other perspective, imagine you have achieved your requirement (there are 2 instances of `MyViewModel`). Now, how are you going to acquire first of those `ViewModel`s?

Comment: Absolutely, but none of your example view models takes in an argument. It might be that I'd like to create a `DogsViewModel(name = "Jack")`, and `DogsViewModel(name ="Bob")`. But that won't be possible, because I will always get the `Jack` view model back. My thought was that I could clear the `JackVM` when I needed to..  But it might be that this is a just a code smell from my side.

Comment: If you want to control on how the `ViewModel` **should** be created, you should prefer [`ViewModelProvider.of(FragmentActivity, ViewModelProvider.Factory)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html), where `Factory` specifies how should particular `ViewModel` be created.

Comment: As an example implementation consider [`GithubViewModelFactory`](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components@master/-/blob/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.java#L29:14).

Comment: That was a more complex usage of `ViewModelProvder.Factory` than I usually do. I'll have a look at it! Many thanks!!

Comment: And I'll leave this bounty open for a few more days before rewarding you it, just to see if something drops in. But thanks for the input again!

Comment: Kotlin + Hungarian Notation... that's mixing old and new.

Comment: The answer makes use of the variable names from the question. Otherwise - absolutely agree.